# Printing problem: How to install a printer profile in darktable

Tags: printing, darktable

How I can add a printer profile to [darktable 2.2.3](http://www.darktable.org/) ?
I am on Ubuntu 16.04. When I select the printing profile in the printer menu it says :

```
> printer ICC profile in home/user/.config/darktable/color/out.
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this problem has not been solved:

1. Create the following directory path:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.config/darktable/color/out
   ```

   `-p` is for creating a path of directories; if the parent directory doesn't exist, it will be created;

   `~` is a [shell function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) for the path to your home directory (`$HOME`).
2. Finally, you should copy the printer profile to the `out` directory.